# How to start an app from kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am working on Android platform, and I wonder if it is possible to start an Android app from the kernel source code. For example, at certain point along the linux kernel resume path, I want to start a specific app, say my custom lock screen app. Is that possible?

***Edit:***

the call_usermodehelper does not work with the "am" utility.
I have code like this in a kernel module:

```
int result = 0;
char *argv[] = { "/system/bin/am", "start", "-n", "com.twitter.android/com.twitter.applib.HomeTabActivity", NULL};
char *argv[] = {"/system/bin/ls", NULL};
static char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", "PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin", NULL };

result = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, 1);
```

but when I insmod, the nothing happens, and result = -8
anyone can help?

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L871 ???

Comment: Starting an Android "app" is typically quite a bit different from starting a process, as it's actually done by sending a request "Intent" to a system component.  That request passes through the kernel Binder IPC driver, so you could probably (non-portably) inject one there.  However, if you can start a generic linux process with arguments, you could run the command line `am` tool which is provided to facilitate sending Intents from ADB - thus avoiding any dependence on Android implementation details.

Comment: yeah, am works well!
I wonder if it is possible to run only one app from the kernel while blocking all the other processes until that app returns. Is that possible?

Comment: Apps don't return.  They also depend on a **lot** of other things.  You are going to have to let android fully start, get zygote up, system server, and all that before sending an Intent will accomplish anything.

Comment: what is boot receiver? so the zygote, the system server etc., which an android app depends on are all user-space process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak for certain about Android, but in vanilla Linux, there's a bunch of API's in kmod.h which can do what you want.  See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw97Kernel-APIs-P1dth-LX) for details.

Comment: there is function in kmod.h
    call_usermodehelper
which can start a user space application