# Modifying Android UI through linux kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

My goal is to show a popup window in the Android UI using linux kernel. Is it possible to do so? I checked the SDM driver(DRM driver for QCOM/adreno devices) but I couldn't find an API which does so. I thought of a solution which would be to open app that shows a pop up on screen but I couldn't find an api for starting android apps from the kernel either. I was able to find some information in this thread [How to start an app from kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827814/how-to-start-an-app-from-kernel)

However I couldn't find any solid information!

**EDIT**
I tried launching telegram as a test through am (and I bypassed selinux denial as well) but nothing happened. Here's the code:

```
static int launch_test(void){
    char *envp[] = {
            "ANDROID_DATA=/data",
            "LOGNAME=shell",
            "HOME=/",
            "ANDROID_STORAGE=/storage",
            "ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app",
            "SHELL=/system/bin/sh",
            "EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/sdcard",
            "ANDROID_CACHE=/cache",
            "USER=shell",
            "TMPDIR=/data/local/tmp",
            "PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin",
            NULL};
    char *argv[] = {"/system/bin/am", "start", "org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity", NULL};

    return call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
}
```

Comment: "My goal is to show a popup window in the Android UI using linux kernel." - Quite a strange goal. Linux Kernel isn't responsible for UI in the user space, so you will unlikely find an appropriate interface here.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It is indeed a strange goal. I figured that launching an app through kernel would be better. Interestingly, using call_usermodehelper to execute am causes a sepolicy denial. I wonder if i can bypass that. I am not sure how to control sepolicy perms in kernel space if its possible at all. I can use sepolicy-inject to bypass that but i am looking for a more persistent solution.